# PHP - increment in recursive function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function:

```
function show_comments(&$comments, $parent_id = 0 ) {
  $comments_list = "";
  $i = 0;
  foreach($comments as $comment) :
    if ($comment["parent_id"] != $parent_id)
        continue;

    $comments_list .= '<div class="comment level-'. $i . '">';
    $i++;
    $comments_list .= "<p>$comment[body]</p>";
    $comments_list .= $this->show_comments($comments, $comment['id_comment']);
    $comments_list .= '</div>';
  endforeach;


  return $comments_list;
}
```

I want for the parent div to have class **level-0** and the direct child of that parent have **level-1** and child of child with **level-1** to have class **level-2** and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to loop through all the comments to build a tree. Or you can keep track of the level_id in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// add a new parameter --------------------------------
//                                                    |
function show_comments(&$comments, $parent_id = 0, $level = 0) {
  $comments_list = "";

  // not needed
  // $i = 0;

  foreach($comments as $comment) :
    if ($comment["parent_id"] != $parent_id)
        continue;

    // use the level parameter ------------------------
    //                                                |
    $comments_list .= '<div class="comment level-'. $level . '">';

    // not needed
    // $i++;
    $comments_list .= "<p>$comment[body]</p>";


    // increment it on recursive calls -----------------------------------------
    //                                                                         |
    $comments_list .= $this->show_comments($comments, $comment['id_comment'], $level + 1);
    $comments_list .= '</div>';
  endforeach;


  return $comments_list;
}
```